# Why the word post in BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface?

Tags: spring

Hi this could be a silly question but I'm curios to know why the word **post** in BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface in Spring. After what are the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` going to be used ? What happened before. I would like to know like why the name.

Answer (score 2):

Please see here for the Bean Lifecycle in Spring:

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-bean-life-cycle/

and here:

https://reflectoring.io/spring-bean-lifecycle/

Thus this is the last processing instance in the bean initialization.

Comment: What did you mean by the last ProcessingInstance ? I know that the implementations of that interface are used before the beans are created. What I would like to know is like the origin of the name. Why the developers decided to named the interface BeanFactoryPostProcessor.

Comment: Bean because the main target for the Class. Factory points towards the Factory Pattern.  PostProcessor is usually something done at last. See the Links i posted. The BeanFactoryPostProcessor is called at last during the initialization.

Comment: Oh ok thanks ! So The BeanFactoryPostProcessor is called at last during the initialization of BeanFactory instances ? I'll be checking the links.